# Как сделать адаптивность блока в неизвестном месте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Задача такая: сверстать адаптивный блок, как на картинке. С версткой блока проблем нет. Проблемой является то, что неизвестно в каком именно месте сайта будет располагаться этот блок. Реализовать нужно исключительно средствами HTML и CSS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.action {
  display: flex;
  background: #FFFDF4;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.action__pict,
.action__content {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.action__pict img {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  min-width: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
  <div class="action__pict">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="action__content">
    <p>С версткой блока проблем нет. Проблемой является то, что неизвестно в каком именно</p>
    <p class="text-right"><a href="#">Link</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```